# How to make http put request with zip file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-request

I want to make a http PUT request with zip file in binary to a web api and get response with http status code.

How to read the file and PUT it with binary ?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: it works find by using http-request module.

http.put({
url: '',
reqBody: fs.createReadStream(‘aa.zip'),
headers: {'Content-Type':'application/zip'}
}, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
return;
}
console.log(res.code, res.headers);
});

Answer (score 8):

You can start with this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');

var req = http.request({
  hostname : HOSTNAME,
  port     : PORT,
  path     : UPLOAD_PATH,
  method   : 'PUT',
});

fs.createReadStream('somefile.zip').pipe(req);
```

You may need to perform some other actions, like proper error handling, setting `Content-Type` headers, etc.

Comment: After fs.createReadStream('somefile.zip').pipe(req); How can I make the put request ?

Comment: var stream = fs.createReadStream('somefile.zip').pipe(req);

Comment: req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message); });

Comment: fs.createReadStream('aaa.zip').pipe(request.put(options, function(err, res, data) {
 if(err)
  console.log('err: ' + err);
 else
  console.log(data);
}));

But it shows : A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented ..

but I did not set any header in the options, it only contains the uri : 

var options = {
 uri:'https://aaa.zzz'
};

Comment: @KevingoTsai `http.request()` makes the `PUT` request when you pipe the file through it. You seem to be using the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, which is fine, but it works (a bit) differently than the plain `http` module that I'm using. As for headers, it _really_ depends on the exact semantics of the API implementation. Perhaps it requires certain headers to be set, I don't know.

Comment: @robertkple Finally I use http-request module, which works fine. the code snippet are follows:

http.put({
url: '',
reqBody: fs.createReadStream(‘aa.zip'),
headers: {'Content-Type':'application/zip'}
}, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
return;
}
console.log(res.code, res.headers);
});

Answer (score 5):

Using request-promise (based on bluebird)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request-promise');

const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'dest url',
    qs: {key: 'value'}, // optional 
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
};

fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(request(options)).then(body =>{
        console.log(body);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js).

The only difference would be, you are using `.put()` instead on `.post()`.