# How to put a PDF with chai-http?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, testing, chai

Alright this is a pretty wholistic question here, as I need to know both about process and best-practices. Critiques be welcome!

I'm writing a test for a `PDF-to-image API` endpoint. As such, I need to `put` the PDF to the `endpoint`. The endpoint will save it locally, convert it, store the sequence of images in an S3 bucket, and then send back an array of URLs. But, since I'm writing this test largely to assist in development, none of that happens yet. I just want to make sure I can receive the PDF at the endpoint, and save it.

**Check out the test code below:**

```
// testing dependencies
const chai = require("chai")
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http")
const should = chai.should()
const server = require('./../index.js')

chai.use(chaiHttp)

// utility dependencies
const fs = require('fs')

describe("PDF upload", () => {
  it("should PUT my pdf", (done) => {
    fs.readFile('./content/pdf/lockheed.pdf', (err, res) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err) }
      else {
        chai.request(server)
          .put('/v1/convert-pdf')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
          .send({ pdf: res })
          .end((err, res) => {
            console.log("got the res")
            if (err) { console.error(err) }
            else { console.log(res.body) }

            done()
          })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Before I set the `Content-Type` header, I would simply get a 413 from the server (request too large). I've set all my timeouts and max request size really big so this really shouldn't be an issue. But now that I have `application/pdf` in the header, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
```

This was much more helpful, and led me to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536461/how-to-make-http-put-request-with-zip-file-in-nodejs) which pipes the file to a request. However, I'm really not sure how to accomplish this via `chai-http` so that my server can successfully get and save the pdf to a local file.

Answer (score 3):

To upload file through `chai-http`, use `attach` instead of `send`. Here is an example:

```
describe("PDF upload", () => {
  it("should PUT my pdf", (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .put('/v1/convert-pdf')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      .attach('fileField', './content/pdf/lockheed.pdf', 'lockheed.pdf')
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log("got the res");
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
        } else {
          console.log('success');
          console.log(res.body)
        }
        done();
      });
  })
})
```

Actually, `chai-http` follows the same API as `SuperAgent`. Please check the [document](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests) for more detail.

Comment: Ah interesting! I'll have to give that a go when I get the chance. I actually ended up attaching it as a Buffer from `fs.readFile`, which got the job done, but I'll be happy to try a more concise solution

Comment: @Corbfon is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can kindly "accept" this answer?