# Node / Javascript - pipe writeStream / file to post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, pipe

I have the following code, it creates a file on a remote server from a test var (just to make sure it worked), but now I need to upload a file and I'm not sure how to actually attach it to the request, here is the code:

```
var dataString = '@test.txt';
var options = {
    uri: 'https://site.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=test.txt',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/binary',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic bXVydGV6LmF....'
    },
    body: dataString 
    //this will create a test file with some text, but I need 
    //to upload a file on my machine instead
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
    var x = {
        error: error,
        response: response,
        body: body
    }
    console.log(x);
}
    request(options, callback);
```

I was thinking something in the lines of:

```
fs.createReadStream('text.txt').pipe({function?})
```

But I'm not sure how to finish this part unfortunately.

**update: 2019**
It's been a LONG time, but someone asked for the solution. I'm not sure if this is how I fixed it tbh or if this code even works, but I found this digging around, give it a try.

Also, Zendesk updated their API at some point, not sure when exactly so this may be old anyways:

```
var uploadAttachment = function() {
var uOptions = {
  uri: 'xxx/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=' + fileName,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/binary',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Basic xxx'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!body) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      var x = {
        error: true,
        message: "Some message",
        err: response
      };
      return next(x);
    }
  }
  if (body && body.error) {
    return next(error);
  }
  if (error) {
    return next(error);
  }

  var jr = JSON.parse(body);
  var uploaded = {};

  if (jr.upload) {
    uploaded = jr.upload;
  }

  attachToComment(uploaded);
}

fs.createReadStream(tempPath + fileName).pipe(request(uOptions, callback));
```

};

I hope this helps, sorry in advance if it does not work, I no longer have access to zendesk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file using POST request in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js)

Comment: The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) say you just pipe it to `request`

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work after a bit of meddling with request.

Comment: @Mankind1023 could you provide the solution here?  I'm running into the same issue.