# How do I send a form with a request promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to use the request-promise library or anything similar to send files via a post request from node to another machine that is running Node. Using the normal request module I could so something like

```
var req = request.post(url, function (err, resp, body) {
 if (err) {
    console.log('Error!');
  } else {
    console.log('URL: ' + body);
  }
});
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', '<FILE_DATA>', {
  filename: 'myfile.txt',
  contentType: 'text/plain'
});
```

This code is from the question: 
[Uploading file using POST request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-fs) however it is not using promises.

Can anyone explain how to do the same thing but with the request-promise library or if there is any other way to promisify this?

Comment: you want `req` to return a promise?

Comment: What is purpose of using `Promise`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) that are linked from the answer you already found, you don't need to use a `.form()` method on the resulting request object, but can simply pass the form as the `formData` option to `request`. You'll be able to do the same with request-promise:

```
requestPromise.post({url: url, formData: {
    file: {
        value: '<FILE_DATA>',
        options: {
            filename: 'myfile.txt',
            contentType: 'text/plain'
        }
    }
}).then(function(body) {
    console.log('URL: ' + body);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error!');
});
```

Alternatively, request-promise still seems to return request instances (just decorated with `then`/`catch`/`promise` methods), so the `form` function should still be available:

```
var req = requestPromise.post(url);
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', '<FILE_DATA>', {
  filename: 'myfile.txt',
  contentType: 'text/plain'
});
req.then(function(body) {
    console.log('URL: ' + body);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error!');
});
```

Comment: I did try this but I end up with an error : Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: write after end

Comment: Which one? Did it work with the non-promisified `request`? And: Is this the exact code you were using? Where does `FILE_DATA` come from? The code I posted should never produce an unhandled rejection.

Comment: I have set data 

        let formData = {
            id: request._id.toString(),
            file: {
                value: fs.createReadStream(request.filePath),
                options: {
                    'filename': request.fileName,
                    'contentType': request.mineType
                }
            }
        };

but not able to get the file in another server 
req.files is getting undefine

Comment: @LaxmanMali You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you post the whole code, of both servers