# Error: write after end in request npm library

Tags: node.js, npm, request

I am trying to send a file via the request npm library, but I keep getting the `write after end` error. What's wrong? How can I fix this?

This is the way I'm doing this:

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const callback = (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode < 400) {
                resolve(body);
            }
            else {
                reject(error); // Write after end
            }
        };
        request({
            url: "https://api.url.com/v2/",
            method: "POST",
            formData: fs.createReadStream("file"),
        }, callback);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to send data is to append the form data to the request:

```js
var req = request.post(url, callback);

var form = req.form();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filepath));
```

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js

Comment: looks like the `Promise` is your problem. Have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813500/how-do-i-send-a-form-with-a-request-promise