# Upload file to another server with request or axios nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a user form where a user can pick a file on their system and upload it to another server using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). It works fine when testing sending it directly to the api. But I need to modify the headers before sending it. So I'm posting to the backend of the client app.

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  //...some axios or request logic

  var fs = require('fs');
  var request = require('request');
  var formData = {
    my_field: 'my_value',
    my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/example.doc'),
  };

  request.post({url:'http://someothereapp/upload-file', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    res.send('good!');
  });

});
```

`axios` or `request` works great for posting normal forms or get request. But when I try to use it to send a file it doesn't work. The above code always returns success but does not upload the file. So i went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js) and still don't understand enough to see what I am missing.

I have authentication and tracking turned off on the other server (local) while testing so i don't have to modify headers. It has the following code that works fine if I send the file directly to it from the web form, but not from my client express app:

```
  // http://someothereapp/upload-file
  router.post('/upload-file', (req, res, next) => {
    let multer = require('multer')
    let p =  path.join(__dirname, '../uploads');
    let storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, p )
      },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log('what is file', file)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
      }
    })

    let upload = multer({
      storage: storage
    }).single('userFile')
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      res.end('File is uploaded')
    })
  });
```

I saw [this](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/789) issue and think it might mean its not possible with axios but how do you do it with request? For example, in the `post ... upload` code, how do i get `my_file` to be the file the user selected in their form? Why is it not failing even though it's not uploading a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the client backend app to the following and it allows me to modify headers and send the form:

```
router.post('/upload-file', function(req, res, next) {
  var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({headers: customHeader});
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://someothereapp' }, function(e) { 
    // will proxy request to http://someothereapp/upload-file
    ...
  });
});
```

The client form (unchanged):

```
<form name='uploadfile'  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="userFile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>


<script>
var form = document.forms.namedItem("uploadfile");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

  var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"),
      oData = new FormData(form);

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "/upload-file", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      // oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
      console.log('Uploaded');
    } else {
      console.log('error', oReq.status);
      // oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.<br \/>";
    }
  };

  oReq.send(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
```

The target server (unchanged):

```
  // http://someothereapp/upload-file
  router.post('/upload-file', (req, res, next) => {
    let multer = require('multer')
    let p =  path.join(__dirname, '../uploads');
    let storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, p )
      },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log('what is file', file)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
      }
    })

    let upload = multer({
      storage: storage
    }).single('userFile')
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      res.end('File is uploaded')
    })
  });
```