# Send PDF to google API via axios on server(NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, pdf, server-side, axios, google-cloud-print

I have problems trying to send a PDF to Google API via [Axios](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#submit).

**Code I tried:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const router = express.Router();
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

const ticketProperties = {
  'version': '1.0',
  'print': {}
};

router.post('/print/sale', async (req, res) => {

    // Generate test PDF
    let doc = new PDFDocument;
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
    doc.fontSize(8)
      .text('Some text example for pdf', 1, 1);
    doc.end();

    // Once the pdf is generated, read it and send it via axios
    axios.post(
      'https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit',
      {
        printerid : 'PRINTER_ID_REMOVED_INTENTIONALLY',
        title: 'pdf print',
        ticket: ticketProperties,
        content : doc,
        contentType: 'application/pdf'
      },
      {
        headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED_INTENTIONALLY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

});
```

**The error I got in** `console.log(error)` when I call that API:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at transformRequest (G:\projects\pos-web\pos-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults.js:51:19)
>       at transform (G:\projects\pos-web\pos-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\transformData.js:16:12)
>       at Object.forEach (G:\projects\pos-web\pos-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\utils.js:224:12)
>       at transformData (G:\projects\pos-web\pos-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\transformData.js:15:9)
>       at dispatchRequest (G:\projects\pos-web\pos-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:37:17)
>       at

I think that error is because I'm writing the file `doc` inside the body of post. Do I need to process it before?

**Notes:**

1. The pdf is generated successfully inside of my project.
2. My first test was sending a text instead of pdf and was OK.
3. I've tried a lot of possible solutions, but give me different errors, maybe I'm understanding wrong how to send a pdf from the server.
   Please If you have another library instead of axios or you know the flow of how to send a pdf from the server, don't hesitate in write it, I'll take it as a good answer.

**More information:**

- about endpoint `https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit` : [Link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#submit)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem, the error was because `ticketProperties` need to be as string: `JSON.stringify(ticketProperties)`, because it is an object.

Despite I solved this problem, I had others problems with Axios package and I decided change `axios` by `request` package to make my request API and It worked. This solution helped me: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js/25345124#25345124)

**code:**

```js
var formData = {
  printerid : 'PRINTER_ID_REMOVED_INTENTIONALLY',
  title: 'pdf print',
  ticket: JSON.stringify(ticketProperties),
  content: fs.createReadStream('output.pdf'),
  contentType: 'application/pdf'
};

request.post(
  {
    url:'https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit',
    formData: formData,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED_INTENTIONALLY'
    }
  },
  function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('upload failed:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    }
  }
);
```

But After It worked, I had more problems with pdf:

1. I need to wait that pdf will be generated with async function `doc.end()` before calling to `fs.createReadStream('output.pdf')`, otherwise I'll have the error `could not convert to pdf`
2. Great upper margin in printing, impossible to reduce it.

After spending hours trying to solve this, I read that is possible send HTML data and I think that is better because it consumes fewer resources and solves the problems described.

Only I changed:

- `content: '<MY_STRING_HTML>'`
- `contentType: 'text/html'`