# Multipart to upload a file throws error

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have been trying to upload a csv file from browser to express js and then from there send a post call to another url to upload the same file using multipart. but it throws error as below

```
Argument error, options.multipart.
Error: Argument error, options.multipart.
    at Multipart.isChunked (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:21:32)
    at Multipart.onRequest (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:104:22)
    at Request.multipart (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\request.js:1270:19)
    at Request.init (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\request.js:406:10)
    at new Request (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\request.js:128:8)
    at request (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\routes\index.js:231:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (d:\avx_node_poc\avx-webApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

Below is express code

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

const prop = {
    protocol: "http:",
    host: '192.168.138.171',
    port: 7300
};

/* uploadAndValidateUsers call */
router.post('/uploadAndValidateUsers', upload.single('userFile'),function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
    request({
        url: prop.protocol + "//" + prop.host + ":" + prop.port + "/avxui/" + req.url,
        headers: {
            "Cookie": req.headers['cookie'],
            "Content-Type": req.headers['content-type']
        },
        method: req.method,
        multipart: req.file
    }).pipe(res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How is the content in `req.file` looking like?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js) seems something you can make it work for your case also.

Comment: @ViKiG { fieldname: 'userFile',
  originalname: 'SampleUser.csv',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
  buffer: <Buffer 55 73 65 72 20 4e 61 6d 65 2c 46 69 72 73 74 20 4e 61 6d 65 2c 4c 61 73 74 20 4e 61 6d 65 2c 50 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64 2c 41 75 74 68 65 6e 74 69 63 61 ... >,
  size: 226 }

Comment: But `multipart` option takes array of objects. Look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `dest` or `storage` option

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

[multer options](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts)

Comment: The error seems to be throwing in the `request` multipart option.