# Send a file in post method in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

Is it possible to send a file (whole file) as POST method in Lambda using node.js ? I can send the form data in a simple way using the modules available. But i want to send the file in lambda to an EndPoint URL where this URL will take care of the manipulation,data rendering etc and send me the response. What i am looking is it possible to implement using any modules or any help is appreciated .

Comment: where will your file be located? What is the problem exactly? Some errors?

Comment: @statut : s3 bucket possibly

Comment: Try something and get it to work, if you have problems ping here for help.

Comment: Did you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25345124/3199240

Comment: @statut : let me try this one. Thanks

Comment: If you are using `AWS Api Gateway` you could follow the following link: [Binary Support for API Integrations with Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)

Comment: @statut : i have implemented in another way and got this as error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608860/upload-failed-error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate