# How to upload a file to server using any node library especially axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am using CURL command to upload a file a server that makes problem in few CLIs.
Only CLIs which are CURL installed is working fine when I am running my node app.

```
let mnmPath = `http://xyz/api/123456/mnm-api`;
exec(`curl -X PUT -H "x-cdn-path:" ${mnmPath } --upload-file abcd.txt`, (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log({status: 1, message: 'Error while uploading Tarball to CDN'});
    }
    console.log({status: 0, message: 'CDN upload completed.'});
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file using POST request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js) except you are just using a PUT request instead of a POST request, requiring the change of just one keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the file somehow, in my example, I've assumed you have a file picker and you can access the data from that

You'll want to send your file to the server using a post request then use promises to catch or resolve based on the success of the request.

> https://github.com/axios/axios
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```js
/*
   example of getting a file from DOM but as long as you
   pass a file to the function should be good 
*/


// es6 promise
function postFileToServer(file) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  axios.post('/your-endpoint', formData)
    .then(res => /* do something with res*/ console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log('upload failed'))
}

function submit() {
  const file = document.getElementById("file").files;
  if (file.length > 0) {
    postFileToServer(file[0])
  }
}
```

```css
input {display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
<input id="file" type="file" />
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```

From the FormData docs

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

Basically, it formats it in an easily manipulatable Object ready to be sent to an external service. You will need to check how the service you're using wants to accept the file.

Comment: have i missed the point if you could explain why the downvote i'll happily change it :)

Comment: I am trying to do this in node side. As I have the file inside the project structure I don't want to use the get `elementById` query. And When I use new FormData(), I am getting reference error.  `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data and ignore the dom stuff then :)

Comment: Thank you so much. The thing is that I am not sure what should be the expected content type when I do --upload-file through curl. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T  So when try the above code I see content-type mismatch error.

Comment: Checked the request. content type is 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', Not sure why it is going like this

Comment: Sorry I'll reply when I have time :) but will help

Comment: @AJAYKUMAR hey man this post explains what content type to send files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data