# Upload files with telegram bot - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I want to upload a `.txt` file to telegram with my javascript bot.
I've seen a few examples in php and python but didn't understand, so I just need a js example to find out.

Should I upload a file first and then `sendDocmuent` or should input in `sendDocmuent`?

I've tried `sendDocument` with `document: 'file.txt'` but didn't work.

Also read about form-data but got nothing!

```
call("sendDocument",{
chat_id: owner,
document: 'file.txt' // or /file.txt or full address (C:...)
});
```

I'm not using any library, here is my call function:

```
const botUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/";
const request = require('request');
function call(method, params, onResponse)
{

var requestData = params;

var data = {
    url: botUrl+method,
    json: true,
    body: requestData
};


request.post(data, function(error, httpResponse, body){
    if (onResponse) {
            if(body)
            {
                onResponse(body.result);
            }
        }
});

}
```

[Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED: This is the code that works for me.**

It seems that what the Telegram API never requires a file name for the sendDocument method:

*File to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a file that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a file from the Internet, or upload a new one using multipart/form-data*

Instead of just sending out the string `'file.txt'`, you need to actually send the contents of the file, as a multipart/form-data, as you had guessed. Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js?answertab=votes#tab-top), you just need to modify the `form` field of the `request` object:

```
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
const token = '752511654:AAGnu88dyi7YsmpZfcaA6XvR26Fy7f2moGo'
const url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendDocument'
const chat_id = "741718736"

let r = request(url, (err, res, body) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log(body)
})

let f = r.form()
f.append('chat_id', chat_id)
f.append('document', fs.createReadStream('file.txt'))
```

Comment: I've updated my post, I prefer not using telegram-bot-api

Comment: Updated my post as well, based on the telegram API!

Comment: Does `let document_to_be_sent = fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.txt')` return anything? 

You could also try with `form.append('custom_file', fs.createReadStream('path/to/file'), {filename: 'file.txt'});`, all in one line

Comment: My file is in root folder, so `fs.createReadStream('file.txt')`.At first I use fs.readFile('file.txt',... and I'm sure the file is ok

Comment: I think should change botUrl+method, tried botUrl+"sendDocument" and that was the respond

Comment: hey @S.s. the code i edited is working for me now. let me know if it does the job for you. the problem was to set the form field as `document` and not `file` or `custom_file`