# Next.js API Forward FormData to External API

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to send a file to an external api, but the post request must come from my backend. I have my client set up as so:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileToUpload', file);
fetch(API_URL, {method: 'POST', body: formData,})
```

I want to make this same request from my backend using this file with different headers. I've tried using a variety of form parsers such as busboy and formidable, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading file using POST request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344879/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-node-js)

Comment: No it does not. The request library is deprecated.